# Running a speech to text python script on flask backed

Tags: html, flask

I have a python script which records audio and convert it to text. I want to render this text on a webpage using flask backend

The python script

```
def speech():

    r = sr.Recognizer()
    text = ""
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)

        print("Please say something")

        audio = r.listen(source)

        print("Recognizing Now .... ")


        # recognize speech using google

        try:
            text =  r.recognize_google(audio)


        except Exception as e:
            print("Error :  " + str(e))
    return text
```

Flask code

```
@app.route('/')
def predict():
    text = spt.speech()
    return render_template('index.html', prediction_text = '{}'.format(text) )
```

HTML Code

```
<form action="{{ url_for('predict')}}">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large">Predict</button>
     </form>
    <textarea rows = "5" cols= "60" name="description">{{ prediction_text }}
      </textarea>
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: The issue is when I click on the button in the webpage it does nothing.

Comment: What do you see in python log?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]